Facebook api to give partner access of business assets
i want to give partner access of business assets to someone via Facebook api, but i have no idea how it can be done.
I tried to use page-id/assigned_users API to assign a page to the user but that also didn't worked, sometimes i got the error, that app-scoped id is invalid and other time i got error: "there is not business linked with this id".
I did some research over chatgpt, and what i got to know is, firstly i need to add the user to business manager and only then i can use above api. But i am not sure if the chatgpt answer is reliable or not.
I have read facebook documentation, but its very confusing !!!
I am new to facebook graph api, so any small help will be really appreciated.
